# How can I find the interior and exterior angles?

Tags: geometry

I got stuck on this question and could not seem to be able to figure it out:

Find one interior angle and one exterior angle of a regular 20-gon.

How could I figure this out? No diagrams were provided, just the word question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of all exterior angles must be $360^\circ$ (intuitively: of you walk around the polygon, then at each turn the angle of your turn would be the exterior angle of that vertex, and if you walk around the polygon then you end up making one rotation). Since there are $20$ exterior angles and they are all congruent (since the polygon is regular), each exterior angle is $360^\circ/20 = 18^\circ$.

Corresponding interior and exterior angles are supplementary, and so each interior angle is $180^\circ-18^\circ = 162^\circ$.

Comment: I see we think alike :)

Comment: Oh, I see now. So, each interior angle would be 162 degrees, while each exterior angle will be 18 degrees. Correct? The other answer seems to be conflicting with this one (switched up results)

Comment: @xFlare: Yes, I apologize about that. I was referring to the central angle when I wrote $360/20$. I'm a noob when it comes to classical geometry terms and paying attention.

Answer (score 2):

I apologize. I mixed up what I was thinking about. The central angle is $360/20 = 18$. This angle forms a triangle with the two other angles being the same since the polygon is regular. To construct this triangle, we  bisected adjacent angles with a rays extending from the center of the polygon. Calling the original angle $\alpha$, the three angles become $\gamma_1=\alpha/2, \gamma_2=\alpha/2, \gamma_3=18$. Hence we have, $\alpha + 18 = 180 \Rightarrow \alpha = 162$ i.e the interior angles are $162$ degrees. Now, since the exterior angles $\beta$ are supplementary to the interior ones i.e $\beta = 180-162=18$.

Comment: @lioness99a: I made an edit. Thank you. I was trying to figure out what was going wrong and realized after your comment that it was terminology.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: the sum of all internal angles of a $n$-sided polygon is $(n-2)\cdot180°$.

Answer (score 0):

The central angle, i.e. the angle subtended by each side measured from the center of its circunscribed circle, is:
$$
2\pi \frac{1}{20}
$$

Hence the requested angles are:
$$
x_{int}=2\pi-2\pi\frac{1}{20}=2\pi \frac{19}{20} \\
x_{ext}=2\pi\frac{1}{20}
$$

Comment: What do you mean by central angle?

Comment: Neither $x_{int}$ nor $x_{ext}$ is correct. Here's a [diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_and_external_angles) defining them. The central angle *is* correct.

Comment: Corrected......